# Why does LSTM performs better when the source target is reversed? (Seq2seq)

Tags: machine-learning, machine-translation

I'm currently reading this paper : https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5346-sequence-to-sequence-learning-with-neural-networks.pdf

Here, the author mentioned that LSTM learns better when the order of the source target is reversed. "Mapping (c,a'), (b,b'), (a,a') (a',b',c' is a translation of a,b,c each) is better." but I don't know why reversing the sentence makes it easy for SGD to map input n output sequence better.

Comment: Section 3.3 of that paper attempts to give an explanation: "While we do not have a complete explanation to this phenomenon, we believe that it is caused by the introduction of many short term dependencies to the data set", etc.

Answer (score 2):

Also the paper said, we do not have a complete explanation to this phenomenon.

But here is kinda explanation about that.

> While we do not have a complete explanation to this phenomenon, we
>   believe that it is caused by the introduction of many short term
>   dependencies to the dataset.
>
> Normally, when we concatenate a source sentence with a target
>   sentence, each word in the source sentence is far from its
>   corresponding word in the target sentence.
>
> As a result, the problem has a large “minimal time lag” [17].
>
> By reversing the words in the source sentence, the average distance
>   between corresponding words in the source and target language is
>   unchanged.
>
> However, the first few words in the source language are now very close
>   to the first few words in the target language, so the problem’s
>   minimal time lag is greatly reduced.
>
> Thus, backpropagation has an easier time “establishing communication”
>   between the source sentence and the target sentence, which in turn
>   results in substantially improved overall performance.